# Какую кодировку использовать, чтоб приложение было платформонезависимым?

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, maven

При разработке пользуюсь **Eclipse Mars2**. Затем коммичу в git. После этого происходит сборка с использованием Maven.
Так вот **Maven** выдает такое предупреждение:
`[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1255 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!`
Какие насторойки мне надо поменять в Eclipse, чтоб приложение стало платформонезависимое?
Никакого воода\вывода на русском в приложении нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавил в `pom.xml`

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
```

Предупреждение перестало появляться, однако на других платформах пока не проверял.

Comment: Всё, что НЕ UTF-8 - должно быть предано огню всеочищения.